# Django @login_required causing issue when submitting forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I am passing a some information to view function by submitting a form and view requires has  @login_required decorator. Here is the template where i'm passing email ID using a from

```
<form action="{% url 'become_booster' %}"  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ profile_user.email }}" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Become a Booster">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the view function

```
@login_required
def become_booster(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        user = CustomUser.objects.filter(email= email)[0]
        tiers = Tiers.objects.filter(user=user)
        form = SubscriptionForm
        return render(request,'select_tier.html',{'tiers':tiers,'form':form})
```

This is working fine when the user logedin already. When user didn't login, @login_required sends them to login and when it comes back request.method is no longer POST. It no longer has that email info. Can someone help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: what method is the request, when it comes from @login_required's login enforcement? GET?

Comment: Yes, it  is GET method.

Answer (score 0):

`@login_required` decorator is used to available that function to registered user who are actually logged in or send to login page or registration page. if you remove `@login_required` from your view function it will be available for unregistered and all type of users.

Comment: I need user to be loged in when they use this view, I don't want this function available to unregistered users.

Comment: so it works that way, the view only available for registered user

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
from django.shortcuts import *
@login_required(login_url='become_booster')
def become_booster(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, email=email)
        tiers = get_list_or_404(Tiers, user=user)
        form = SubscriptionForm
        return render(request,'select_tier.html',{'tiers':tiers,'form':form})
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        # Something like this
        # return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'profile_user': user_object_which_contains_email})
```

Comment: This might work except I won't have access to 'user_object_which_contains_email' when it comes back from login page.